# Copy files automatically from usb to specific folder with specific extensions

Tags: loops, batch-file, copy, cmd, backup

I have huge amount of flash drives and I need to backup my files on specific folder (for example C:\Backup).

There are two problems :
1. I need to backup files with .doc and .docx extension only.
2. When flash drive is inserted, I want that files would copy automatically.

(It's loop if I remember)

Is there any batch solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

[try this tutorial for autoplay USB](http://visualdesigning.com/autorun-usb/)

Then, i am thinking, instead of the autoplay.exe you can set it to run a batch file instead.
In that batch file use the [xcopy](http://www.computerhope.com/xcopyhlp.htm) command.